# UITextView cursor has completely disappeared while editing

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uitextview

I set a UITextView to editable and made it first responder. This used to work just fine but recently I noticed that the cursor is simply missing. I can type on the onscreen keyboard and the characters appear, but the cursor never does. Can anyone guess what is going wrong? The UITextView is a subview of a table cell, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

Your cursor hasn't disappeared. It's white!

Use:

```
[self.tableView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I was hit by this one - filed as rdar://16766935. Would suggest duping it - it's nasty gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

I just hit the same snag with a UITextView in a UITableViewCell.  There seems to be a conflict between the cell selection styles and the cursor display.

Changing the cell selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone gets the cursor back:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

I haven't figured out any other work around yet...

Comment: Ah ha, that explains it. I had just set that to gray, because the blue background has been annoying me. Now the background is white, which is probably better than gray actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same symptoms, but created the problem in another manner.

I made my text view first responder in a method that was called before the text view was visible (in viewWillLayoutSubviews for parent view). The text view displayed with keyboard up, and characters typed displayed in the text view, but no insertion point cursor displayed (and tint color was correct).

I realized calling firstResponder on a textView before the view is ready to display was my problem, and fixed it by making the text view first responder in viewDidAppear.

Hopefully this will help others that the first two fixes don't.